# FormBuilder code suggestions for POCO

Tags: c#, xml

I am constructing a form builder in ASP.NET and I am wanting help with the structure of my POCO classes I have the following so far. I just don't see why I need to add to a list and then process it further again would their be a neater way to return a list of .net controls just to add to `Panel` using `LoadControl(controlname)`.

POCO Class

```
public class FormClass
    {

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        // This may actually work with Type, but I'm not so sure
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public bool key { get; set; }
        public bool required { get; set; }
        public string ControlType { get; set; }


    }
```

And then I'm using the following code to populate a list for further processing:

```
    PortalContext DBConext = new PortalContext();
    List<FormClass> formData = new List<FormClass>();
    List<FormStructure> frmstructList = new List<FormStructure>();
    public List<FormStructure> GetFormDataFromService()
    {   // XNamespace xNamespace = "http://CompanyName.AppName.Service.Contracts";



        Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(@"c:\form.xml");
        XNamespace ns = xdoc.GetDefaultNamespace();
        var classDetails = from classDetail in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "ClassDetails")
                           select new FormClass
                           {
                               name = (string)classDetail.Element(ns + "name"),
                               type = (string)classDetail.Element(ns + "type"),                                  
                               displayName = (string)classDetail.Element(ns + "displayName"),
                               length = (int)classDetail.Element(ns + "length"),
                               key = (bool)classDetail.Element(ns + "key"),
                               required = (bool)classDetail.Element(ns + "required"),
                           };

        foreach (FormClass classDetail in classDetails)
        {
              FormStructure frmstruct = new FormStructure();
              frmstruct.FormStructureId = newGuid;
              frmstruct.name = classDetail.name;
              frmstruct.displayname = classDetail.displayName;
              frmstruct.FormKey = classDetail.key;
              frmstruct.Required = classDetail.required;
              frmstruct.ClassName = "Incident";

              if (classDetail.type == "System.String")
                  frmstruct.ControlType = "TextBox";

              if (classDetail.type == "System.Enum") //to be dropdown
                  frmstruct.ControlType = "DropDown";

              if (classDetail.type == "System.DateTime")//date picker            
                  frmstruct.ControlType = "DateTimePicker";

              if (classDetail.type == "System.Boolean")
                  frmstruct.ControlType = "RadioButton";






              frmstructList.Add(frmstruct);


        }
        return frmstructList;


    }
```

XML Data

```
  <name>DisplayName</name>

  <displayName>Display Name</displayName>

  <parent>Object</parent>

  <type>System.String</type>

  <length>4000</length>

  <key>false</key>

  <required>false</required>

</ArrayOfClassDetails>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Your naming conventions are a bit off. Property names (i.e. in `FormClass`) are commonly `PascalCase`.
2. If you are not married to the XML file structure (i.e. it's under your control) then you can simplify the de/serialization quite a lot by using the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

   ```
   public class ClassDetails
   {
       public List<FormClass> Models { get; set; }
   }

   public static class XmlUtils
   {

       public static void Save<T>(T obj, string filename, string namespace)
       {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), namespace);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
            }
       }

       public static T Load<T>(string filename, string namespace)
       {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), namespace);
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(writer);
            }
       }
   }
   ```

   then you can load/save the file with:

   ```
   var details = XmlUtils.Load<ClassDetails>(@"c:\form.xml", "http://CompanyName.AppName.Service.Contracts");

   ...

   XmlUtils.Save(details, @"c:\form.xml", "http://CompanyName.AppName.Service.Contracts");
   ```
3. Rather than having a big if-else cascade I'd use a dictionary to map the types:

   ```
   Dictionary<string, string> ModelToFormTypeMap = 
       new Dictionary<string, string> {
             { "System.String", "TextBox" },
             { "System.Enum", "DropDown" },
             ...
           };
   ```

   then with an addition of a little bit of Linq you get

   ```
   XmlUtils.Load<ClassDetails>((@"c:\form.xml", "http://CompanyName.AppName.Service.Contracts")
           .Models
           .Select(m => new FormStructure 
                        {
                             FormStructureId = newGuid,
                             name = m.name,
                             displayname = m.displayName,
                             FormKey = m.key,
                             Required = m.required,
                             ClassName = "Incident",
                             ControlType = ModelToFormTypeMap[m.type]
                        })
            .ToList();
   ```